# nuxt.js - build ssr with missing pages

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, nuxt.js, server-side-rendering

I have a problem with nuxt build with ssr and missing pages on my website. Due to our deployment process, the same steps are executed on different instances, resulting in unexplained errors. The instances are built identically and the same code is being pulled before the build is started. However, in some cases, there are different builds.

[instance1 - server section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iosFg.png)

[instance2 - server section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3WGy.png)

it seems as if the pages don't exist at all, which is why the users of the page only get an error page. The server-built pages are missing, although they seem to be available for the client.
[instance1 - client section](https://i.stack.imgur.com/um9rJ.png)

By repeating the deployment process only for the "broken" instance, a correct result can be achieved. I am using Node v14.17.0, Yarn v1.22.4, Webpack v4.46.0, Nuxt v2.15.4 and have not found anything causing similar problems. and I have no idea where to start.
ps. the same procedure works in my development environment and for our staging server. the structure of the staging and production server are identical, also the same packages are used.

deployment steps:

1. connect to server
2. checkout master, git pull
3. stop service with current yarn start
4. run yarn install (package.json could be updated from git pull)
5. run yarn build
6. start service where yarn start will be executed

Comment: So, all the pages are always properly generated locally? You can never replicate the buggy behavior found on production? Do you have any `.nuxt` or not-to-be-used directories pulled too? (I'm basically asking if you generated your project with the CLI and have a proper `.gitinore`) A starting point would be to share your `nuxt.config.js`, your `package.json`, double check that the production environment is using the needed package versions and to tell us which commands are run when deploying on production. Also, to debug even further: turn off JS to see SSR'ed pages. Where do you host the app?